# Menu not visible in Eclispe SDK after installation

Tags: java, eclipse

I have recently installed Eclipse SDK 2019-06 in Ubuntu 14.04, But not able to see any menu/options like Windows, Help etc on top. How to make it visible?

Comment: Note: Eclipse Luna is 8 releases and 5 years out of date. Why are you using such  an old version?

Comment: This might be related to the GTK version you have. Ubuntu 14.04 is pretty old and although it is a LTS version, there are only security updates for some time now. Does `export SWT_GTK3=0` before running Eclipse from the terminal, has any effect?